# Get custom taxonomy list on custom post type in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I am using WordPress 4.7 and created custom post type and custom taxonomy for it.
My custom post type is 'products' and custom taxonomy is 'type'.
To get all the taxonomies of 'type', I used following code.

```
<?php
   $terms = get_terms( 'type' );
   foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo '<p>' .$term->name. '</p>';
   }
?>
```

But it returned empty array so I studied hard to find answer and found hint.
I have inspected the executed queries by get_terms('type') function.
They executed two important queries.

First query

```
SELECT    t.*, tt.* FROM wp_terms AS t    INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('type') ORDER BY t.name ASC
```

Next query

```
SELECT term_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_termmeta WHERE term_id IN (10,11) ORDER BY meta_id ASC
```

And I make sense reason why it returned empty array.
The termmeta was provided since WordPress4.4 and I use WordPress4.7.
Because of second query it returned empty query.
But still now I can't find right function to get all custom taxonomies for my products custom post type.
I will be very glad anyone let me know how to do it in WordPress4.7
I can't use lower version only for it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) recommends to add an array as arguments.
In the past the first argument was a taxonomy sting. It's not anymore. This should not matter but still it's probably the best first place to start.

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'type',
) );
```

Comment: Thanks.But still it return empty array,Did you see 2 queries executed?
The first is the right query to get all taxonomies,It returns right array,
But because of 2nd array, they return empty array.
What I'm getting at is how to avoid executing 2nd query or which function should i use instead of get_terms().

Answer (score 4):

Try This code

```
<?php
    $terms = get_terms( array(
                'taxonomy' => 'type'
            ));
    print_r($terms);

    foreach($terms as $term) {
        echo '<p>'.$term->name.'</p>';
    }
?>
```

You can view more detail of `get_terms()` at [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)

Comment: Thanks. But it returns empty array as well

Comment: Please, check your taxonomy type