# Show current taxonomy name - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I think is very simple, but I couldn't  be able to get the answer I need. I just want to show the info of my custom post in the custom post single page.

My custom post are named *Papers* and the custom taxonomy name is *Territorios* which have:

- Lima
- Huancayo
- Barcelona
- Pasco

So, if I have a *Paper* which *Territorios* is LIMA, I need LIMA to show in the single-papers.php template.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the taxonomy values of a custom post type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39831177/15040627)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get custom taxonomy list on custom post type in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41362035/15040627)